# bug text area autofocus react

Tags: reactjs, textarea

There's a bug with the autofocus on react. When my application renders a text area with autofocus=true, it seems to refresh the whole page.

Here is my code:

```
render() {
    const {formData} = this.props;

    return (
        <div className={`section-devis__window ${this.props.classNames}`}>
            <div className="section-devis__window__1">
                <div className={"oneChoice-form__box u-margin-bottom-small"}>
                    <Icon.Clipboard/>{` ${formData[FORM_FIELD.QUESTION]}`}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className={"textFieldForm__box-field"}>
                <textarea
                    className={"textFieldForm__box-field__input"}
                    type='text'
                    autoFocus={true}
                    spellCheck={false}
                    placeholder={'Votre réponse'}
                    onChange={(e) => this.setState({response: e.target.value})}
                />
            </div>
            <div className={"textFieldForm__btn-container"}>
                <button className={"textFieldForm__btn-container__nxt-btn"}
                        onClick={this.pressNextBtn}
                >
                    Suivant
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Most likely not an actual bug. [Does this help?](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/5534)

Comment: Since autofocus deals only with the first render, you may want to check out [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html). One of the suggested uses for refs is managing focus.